# Can I create a custom default vpc with my own cidr and settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

GCP is so much better than aws in this regard. In GCP I can have a "default" vpc/network and have all my custom settings for it. I want the same thing for aws.

I have stuff in many regions. I dont need complex networking just VPCs with my own cidrs in many regions. Would be nice to have these be the "default" so I dont need to worry about hardcoding VPC IDs and subnet IDs in all my deployment automation

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a default VPC in every region, but you can't customise it. The default VPC is somewhat permissive, made to be easy to get started for beginners, so I use automation to delete it.

The best option for you might be to write a simple CloudFormation template and have parameters so you can customise to each region. I haven't tested this but it should be pretty close at least.

VPC ([docs and example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html)). Change this template to customise as you like. Alternately find a VPC template that's fully written, AWS has plenty scattered across their website, or there are some [here](https://templates.cloudonaut.io/en/stable/vpc/). You may just need to parameterise them for the CIDR block and VPC name.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  VPCCIDR:
    Description: CIDR for the VPC
    Type: String
  VPCName:
    Description: Namefor the VPC
    Type: String

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPCCIDR
      Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: !Ref VPCName
```

You'll have to add subnets to the template, I haven't done that for you, but [look here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) it should be easy. If you want an internet gateway you'll need to add that too.

Parameters file (has to be json, one per region, choose a different CIDR block)

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "VPCCIDR",
    "ParameterValue": "10.1.0.0/16"
  }, 
  {
    "ParameterKey": "VPCName",
    "ParameterValue": "Ohio VPC"
  }
]
```

Then run it in a few regions

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --profile --stack-name vpc-ohio --region us-east-2 --template-body file://vpc.yaml --parameters file://vpc-ohio.json
aws cloudformation create-stack --profile --stack-name --region ap-southeast-2 vpc-sydney --template-body file://vpc.yaml --parameters file://vpc-sydney.json
```

If you want to change your VPC